# How to checkout/switch to remote branch and create local copy while discarding local changes?

Tags: git, checkout

I want to checkout a remote branch, create a local copy and pull/update with current remote branch while at the same time ignore changes to the currecntly selected local branch(a different branch)?

I dont want to stash my changes to the current local branch. I want to discard them, pull new branch localy nad checkout.

I tried this command but it keeps asking me to stash my local changes from the current branch:

```
sudo git switch -c fix/my_branch origin-http/fix/my_branch
```

this is the message I get:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    my_local_file.txt
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$ git reset --hard
```

Or stash and discard your stashes changes:

```
$ git add .
$ git stash
$ git stash clear
```

Comment: thanks that works as well but I found another way I ll post below, cheers!

Comment: @KZiovas Yeah "git switch" is too new for me (2019) :p . This answer'll also work if you're using checkout instead of switch

Comment: @KZiovas And also, please mark this topic as solved, even with your own answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answer works as well but this solution I found seems more concise:

```
sudo git switch -cf fix/my_branch origin-http/fix/my_branch
```

simply adding the `-f` parameter in the git switch